# How can I create DI bindings for generic types in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, kotlin

I'm trying to find a Kotlin-based dependency injection system that will allow me to bind generic types like `Foo<T>` and resolve `Foo<Int>`, `Foo<String>`, etc. as needed.

Kodein seems to be one of the more popular DI frameworks and I've looked into that, but don't see how it's possible. [Issue #83](https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/issues/83) in the Kodein repository has some discussion around this topic.

In my case, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```kotlin
import com.atpgroup.testmaster.domain.ExecutableNode
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

annotation class TypeClass
annotation class Instance

/**
 * Represents a catalog of nodes.
 *
 * Factory functions to generate nodes are initially registered to this catalog during setup and used to create
 * instances of nodes.
 */
interface NodeCatalog {
    fun <U : ExecutableNode> resolve(nodeType: KClass<U>, id: String): U
}

/**
 * Simplifies resolution of nodes from a reified context.
 */
inline fun <reified T : ExecutableNode> NodeCatalog.resolve(id: String) = resolve(T::class, id)

/**
 * Dummy implementation of a node catalog.
 */
class DummyNodeCatalog : NodeCatalog {
    override fun <U : ExecutableNode> resolve(nodeType: KClass<U>, id: String): U = TODO("not implemented")
}

/**
 * A type class representing the set of types that can behave like numbers.
 */
@TypeClass
interface Num<T>

// Int and Double both behave like numbers.
@Instance object IntNumInstance : Num<Int>
@Instance object DoubleNumInstance : Num<Double>

/**
 * An executable node that adds two numbers together.
 *
 * @param T the type of the numbers that will be added together
 */
class AddNode<T>(override val id: String, private val N: Num<T>) : ExecutableNode {
    override suspend fun execute() = TODO("not implemented")
}

// Resolve two "add nodes" that operate on different types of numbers.
val catalog = DummyNodeCatalog()
val addInts = catalog.resolve<AddNode<Int>>("integer adder")
val addDoubles = catalog.resolve<AddNode<Double>>("double adder")
```

In C# this is pretty straightforward using Autofac. The snippet below is a working implementation in C# of what I'd like:

```C#
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace Experiment
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<IntNumInstance>().As<INum<int>>();
            builder.RegisterType<DoubleNumInstance>().As<INum<double>>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Add<>));

            var container = builder.Build();
            var addA = container.Resolve<Add<int>.Factory>()("add integers");
            var addB = container.Resolve<Add<double>.Factory>()("add doubles");
            Console.WriteLine(addA);
            Console.WriteLine(addB);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    interface INum<T> {}
    class IntNumInstance : INum<int> {}
    class DoubleNumInstance : INum<double> {}

    class Add<T>
    {
        public delegate Add<T> Factory(string id);

        public Add(string id, INum<T> N)
        {
            Id = id;
            this.N = N;
        }

        public string Id { get; }

        private INum<T> N { get; }

        public override string ToString() => $"Add Node ({Id} - {N})";
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Add Node (add integers - Experiment.IntNumInstance)
Add Node (add doubles - Experiment.DoubleNumInstance)
```

Comment: and what exactly does not work for you? The DI of the different `ExecutableNode`s?

Comment: I don't know to configure Kodein (or any other DI container) to be able to resolve generic types with different type arguments. The first code snippet shows how I'd like to be able to resolve generic types, the question I have is how to register bindings with a DI container to permit that.

Comment: Or in other words - how do I create a working implementation of `NodeCatalog`?

Comment: Based on discussions in the Kodein Slack channel it seems like this is impossible. I've worked around this by not using Kodein and instead doing the most God-awful and hacky reflection-based source-code-manipulation-during-compilation imaginable. But it works.